# MySql 5.7 ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I'm trying to figure out without disabling "only_full_group_by" in my.ini

here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  p.title,
  COUNT(t.qty) AS total 
FROM
  payments t 
  LEFT JOIN products AS p 
    ON p.id = t.item 
WHERE t.user = 1 
GROUP BY t.item
ORDER BY t.created DESC;
```

and tables:

Payments:

```
id     item   user   created
============================
1      1      1      2017-01-10
2      2      1      2017-01-11
3      3      1      2017-01-12
4      4      1      2017-01-13
5      1      1      2017-01-14
```

Products:

```
id     title    created
==========================
1      First     2016-12-10
1      Second    2016-12-11
1      Third     2016-12-12
1      Fourth    2016-12-13
```

The final result should look lie:

```
Name    Total
First   2
Second  1
Third   1
Fourth  1
```

But if I change my query to `GROUP BY t.item, t.created` Error is gone, but I end up with five records instead of four, which is not what I want. Since I'm grouping items based on "item" field, there should be only four records

Comment: Why do you count `t.qty`? With an outer join on `products` you should rather be counting a column in `products`, e.g. `COUNT(p.id)`, so as to count zero when there is no match.

Comment: I suppose the IDs in table `products` are really 4-3-2-1 and not 1-1-1-1? (So 'First' is item 4 which has the latest `created` date in `payments` and comes hence first when ordering by `t.created DESC` as shown by you in the desired result.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT p.title, COUNT(t.qty) AS total 
-------^
FROM payments t LEFT JOIN
     products AS p 
     ON p.id = t.item 
WHERE t.user = 1 
GROUP BY t.item
---------^
ORDER BY t.created DESC;
---------^
```

The pointed to places have issues.  Notice that the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` are referring to different column.   In a `LEFT JOIN`, you (pretty much) always want to aggregate by something in the *first* table, not the second.

The `ORDER BY` is another problem.  You are not aggregating by this column, so you need to decide which value you want.  I am guessing `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT p.title, COUNT(t.qty) AS total 
FROM payments t LEFT JOIN
     products AS p 
     ON p.id = t.item 
WHERE t.user = 1 
GROUP BY p.title
ORDER BY MAX(t.created) DESC;
```

I will also add that `COUNT(t.qty)` is suspect.  Normally `qty` refers to "quantity" and what you want is the sum:  `SUM(t.qty)`.

Comment: does that mean if I select multiple columns from first table, that all of them needs to be aggregated?

Comment: @Alko . . . That is a best practice, yes.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two `t.created` for item 1. So decide by which you want to sort. E.g.:

```
ORDER BY MIN(t.created) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me you query should by group by p.title

```
  SELECT 
    p.title,
    COUNT(t.qty) AS total 
  FROM
    payments t 
    LEFT JOIN products AS p 
      ON p.id = t.item 
  WHERE t.user = 1 
  GROUP BY p.title;
```

or

```
  SELECT 
    p.title,
    COUNT(t.qty) AS total 
  FROM
    payments t 
    LEFT JOIN products AS p 
      ON p.id = t.item 
  WHERE t.user = 1 
  GROUP BY p.title
  order by p.created;
```

then for  "But if I change my query to GROUP BY t.item, t.created Error is gone"  remember that starting from  mysql 5.7 if you use selected  column not in group by  you have an error ..

If you really need  you can disable using a proper set for sql mode eg

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

And last the column in order don't  have effect on group by and on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY param ..  but if  column i order by is not in select have pratically no sense

Comment: even if I GROUP BY title, still gives me 5 records, instead of four

Comment: I have removed  .. the order by .. try check again .. and added  aversion with p.created order by .answer updated .